# print output to 2 seperate column in shell script

Tags: shell, for-loop

I'm developing a shell script that is used to comparing performance of IPv4 and IPv6, I would like to print out the values in format:

```
line_number, IPv4_average_speed    IPv6_average_speed
```

This is the part of the code that is the main of my script:

```
for i in $(head -100 "${1}" | cut -d ',' -f2)
        do
            #status="alive";

            ping -c3 "${i}" > /dev/null
            if [ $? -eq 0 ]
            then
                status_v4="alive";
            else
                status_v4="dead";
                echo "Cannot ping the host "${i}"";
            fi

            ping6 -c3 "${i}" > /dev/null
            if [ $? -eq 0 ]
            then
                status_v6="alive";
            else
                status_v6="dead";
            fi

            if [ "$status_v4" == "alive" ] && [ "$status_v6" == "alive" ]
            then
                ((line_number++))
                ping -c3 "${i}" | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d '/' -f 2 | echo "$line_number,$(sed 's/$/ ms/')";     
                ping6 -c3 "${i}" | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d '/' -f 2 | echo "$line_number,$(sed 's/$/ ms/')";    
            fi                      
        done
```

I'm just able to print output like this, for example:

```
1, 6.542 
1, 5.345
```

But what I want is:

```
1, 6.542 5.345
```

I have tried to save the output of each `ping` into a variable, then use `awk`, but actually I messed up the code.

I changed the part of the code inside the last `if` statement to be like this:

```
ipv4=$(ping -c3 "${i}" | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d '/' -f 2)
ipv6=$(ping6 -c3 "${i}" | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d '/' -f 2) 
awk '{print "$line_number $ipv4 $ipv6" $1 $2 $3}'
```

And it print out nothing on screen. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Can you share the errors? It might help solve the problem. Also: piping ping to tail to awk to cut to echo(?) cannot be a tidy solution.

Comment: it is, you can try it with ping only, it print out nicely :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
{
  echo ${line_number},
  ping  -c3 "${i}" | awk -F/ '/^rtt/ {print $5}'
  ping6 -c3 "${i}" | awk -F/ '/^rtt/ {print $5}'
} | paste -d " " - - -
```

The reason this failed:

```
awk '{print "$line_number $ipv4 $ipv6" $1 $2 $3}'
```

is because you're trying to expand shell variables in a single quoted string. You probably want something like

```
awk -v ln=$line_number -v ip4=$ipv4 -v ip6=$ipv6 'BEGIN {printf "%d, %s %s\n" ln, ip4, ip6}'
```

But a shell printf command is clearly much simpler

```
printf "%d, %s %s\n" $line_number $ipv4 $ipv6
```